MultiIndex Pivot Table Pandas
I am trying to replicate a pivot table using pandas using a sample dataset below from a much larger table:
year  type   status   paid  balance  count
2000  bank1  active   15      21      1
2001  bank2  default  27      40      1
2002  bank3  payoff   35     150      1
2003  bank4  closed   20      80      1
.       .       .      .       .      .
.       .       .      .       .      .
.       .       .      .       .      .

The following pivot table gives me this output:
pivot = (pd.pivot_table(df,
                        index=['status', 'type'],
                        values=['paid', 'balance', 'count'],
                        aggfunc="sum")
           .reset_index()
           .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

Which outputs:

status    type    paid    balance   count

active   bank1     500      850         6
         bank2     450      800         8
         bank3     225      940        11
         bank4     580      990        15

payoff   bank1     xxx     xxx        xxx
         bank2     xxx     xxx        xxx
         bank3     xxx     xxx        xxx
         bank4     xxx     xxx        xxx
.
.
.
closed   bank1     xxx     xxx        xxx
         bank2     xxx     xxx        xxx
         bank3     xxx     xxx        xxx
         bank4     xxx     xxx        xxx

I desire this output (which is identical to an excel pivot table):
 type      paid    balance   count
 active    1755     3580       40  (running totals for active)
 bank1      500      850        6
 bank2      450      800        8
 bank3      225      940       11
 bank4      580      990       15

 payoff    xxx     xxx        xxx  (running totals)
 bank1     xxx     xxx        xxx
 bank2     xxx     xxx        xxx
 bank3     xxx     xxx        xxx
 bank4     xxx     xxx        xxx
.
.
.
 closed    xxx     xxx        xxx (running totals)
 bank1     xxx     xxx        xxx
 bank2     xxx     xxx        xxx
 bank3     xxx     xxx        xxx
 bank4     xxx     xxx        xxx


What's the question? Like, what do you need help with? Check out [ask] for tips, including how to write a good title. You can [edit] to clarify.

This might help: How can I pivot a dataframe? This question exhaustively compares the different options.

And please provide a reproducible pandas example. The data you've provided here doesn't have any repeats of status or type, so it's not very helpful, and that output doesn't match that input.

What do you mean by the blank rows in the output? Pandas can't group the tables it outputs, AFAIK. That's why you'd need to have the status column separate. But you could certainly format it yourself.

To do so, you first need to create the pivot table as you did, after which you create a function that will compute the sub-totals:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'year': [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003],
    'type': ['bank1', 'bank2', 'bank3', 'bank4', 'bank1', 'bank2', 'bank3', 'bank4'],
    'status': ['active', 'active', 'closed', 'active', 'payoff', 'payoff', 'payoff', 'payoff'],
    'paid': [15, 27, 35, 20, 10, 20, 30, 25],
    'balance': [21, 40, 150, 80, 10, 40, 60, 70],
    'count': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['status', 'type'], values=['paid', 'balance', 'count'], aggfunc='sum')

def add_totals_and_format(pivot):
    all_data = []
    for status, group in pivot.groupby(level=0):
        total = group.sum().rename(('total',))
        total_df = pd.DataFrame([total], index=[f'{status} totals'])
        
        formatted_group = pd.concat([total_df, group.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)])
        all_data.append(formatted_group)
    
    return pd.concat(all_data)

pivot_with_totals = add_totals_and_format(pivot)

print(pivot_with_totals)


which gives you
               balance  count  paid
active totals      141      3    62
bank1               21      1    15
bank2               40      1    27
bank4               80      1    20
closed totals      150      1    35
bank3              150      1    35
payoff totals      180      4    85
bank1               10      1    10
bank2               40      1    20
bank3               60      1    30
bank4               70      1    25

